# Is there a way to add more details about the current logged user in User.Identity in .NET CORE API and access it in the services

Tags: authentication, .net-core, owin

I separated the business logic from the controller and all the data access is in my service class. and the constructor is calling respective services. but I'm not able to access "User.Identity.Name" in the services. basically i need all the details about the current user in all the services. please help me im stuck in this problem for more than two weeks.. :(

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Share your code as a [mcve] and point out the specific challenge in the code.

Comment: Check the claims of the Identity: User.Claims. Does one of the claims contain the name? What is the claim type? Also show the code from startup where you configure the authentication and authorization.